# PHP Converting SQL date to different format showing as a string of numbers

Tags: php, mysql, date, strtotime

I have a query which lists out rows from a database. I need to convert the standard SQL date format from `Y-m-d H:i:s` (2001-03-10 17:16:18) to `F j, Y, g:i a` (March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm) when echoing out the date.

To convert the date format I have

```
$sqlDate = $row->updateDate;
$updateDate = $phpDate = strtotime( $sqlDate );
$sqlDate = date( 'F j, Y, g:i a', $phpDate );
```

then echo out

```
echo $phpDate;
```

When $phpDate is echoed out  it shows as a string of 10 numbers like this: 1454241452

I am not sure what those numbers are... seconds?

What am I doing wrong within the conversion of `strtotime` ? Or would my problem lie elswere?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are echoing the wrong date var, try it like this:

```
$sqlDate = $row->updateDate;  # get date from database 
$utime = strtotime($sqlDate); # this is unix time (check php.net/date)
$newdate = date( 'F j, Y, g:i a', $utime); # convert unix time to desired format
echo $newdate;
```

or in one line:

```
$newdate = date( 'F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime($row->updateDate));
echo $newdate;
```

Comment: That is elegantly simple! Works like a charm. I see what was wrong now. Also I noted I had `$updateDate = $phpDate = strtotime( $sqlDate );` while $updateDate didn't even exist.

 - Thank you for your answer. I will check as accepted in 5 minutes when it lets me!

Answer (score 0):

Your $phpDate variable value store strtotime but not correct.

You change your code some modify like this

```
$sqlDate = $row->updateDate;
$updateDate = $phpDate = strtotime( $sqlDate );
$sqlDate = date( 'F j, Y, g:i a', $phpDate );
$phpDate= date( 'F j, Y, g:i a', $phpDate );
echo $phpDate;
```

This code working fine

this code useful for You :)